# Print 2 elements in a list

Tags: dart

I am trying to add all elements to a list, Here is my code the code below will run in dart pad.

```
void main() {
  mydates();
}

class Event {
  const Event(this.date, this.title, this.description);

  final DateTime date;
  final String title;
  final String description;

  @override
  String toString() => title;
}

List<Event> eventList = [
  Event(DateTime(2021, 1, 1), "Buy milk",
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Pellentesque sem"),
  Event(DateTime(2021, 1, 1), "Go to gym",
      "Duis congue enim ut justo interdum, id porta turpisvarius"),
  Event(DateTime(2021, 1, 2), "Running",
      "Fusce in varius lorem. Praesent accumsan metus at semfaucibus"),
];

//Function
mydates() {
  var eventDayMap = <DateTime, List<Event>>{};
  for (var event in eventList) {
    print(event.date); // Prints each element in the List<Event>
    print(event.title);
    print(event.description);

    // Adding them to the eventDayMap
    // Creates a new list
    // Adds only the date and title
    (eventDayMap[event.date] ??= []).add(event);
  }
  print(eventDayMap);
  //print(eventDayMap.runtimeType);
  return eventDayMap;
}
```

What is returned is this

```
{2021-01-01 00:00:00.000: [Buy milk, Go to gym], 2021-01-02 00:00:00.000: [Running]}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the {date, title, description} and there can be many title and descriptions for one date.

```
{2021-01-01 00:00:00.000: [Buy milk, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sem ],
[Go to gym, Duis congue enim ut justo interdum, id porta turpis varius], 
2021-01-02 00:00:00.000: [Running, Fusce in varius lorem. Praesent accumsan metus at sem faucibus]}
```

So I can have a title and a description returned.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Dart comes with a default formatter which is great to make code look consistent with other Dart code. If you are using DartPad, you can activate the formatter by clicking on "Format". It is basically what I did to your question to make it actually readable. (also added a return value to your `mydates()` method since you should always specify types for method signatures).

Comment: @julemand101 Thanks, I did the format in Dartpad and it said no formatting changes, I edited your edit as I though I pasted it incorrectly :(

Comment: @JohnnyQ Ah that would also explain the broken lines you got in the code I also ended up fixing before the formatter would run. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your problem is depends on what your *goal* is.

If you want to create a valid JSON map, you will want to represent each element by a list. That doesn't appear to be the case since your keys are `DateTime` objects, not strings.

If you just want to be able to *print* the events, for debugging, then your problem is the `String toString() => title;` declaration.

Your map is fine, it maps from dates to `Event` objects. That's what you'll want.

Then you try to print that map, which calls `toString` on each value, which only returns the *title* string.
That only matters if you actually print the map, which you shouldn't be doing (except for debugging).

If you change `toString` to

```dart
String toString() => "[$title, $description]";
```

you'll likely get what it appears you're looking for.

Comment: Great that helped me a lot, My goal is to create LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<Event>> with the Datetime that will connect to my calendar and then have a title and description of the event. Which I think I can accomplish now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked it out after a long time trying to do it my self it comes to me after posting it here.

I needed to return a List instead of a single event.

```
void main() {
  mydates();
}

class Event {
  const Event(this.date, this.title /*, this.description*/);

  final DateTime date;
  final List title;
  //final String description;

  //@override
  //String toString() => title;
}

List<Event> eventList = [
  Event(DateTime(2021, 1, 1), [
    "Buy milk",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sem"
  ]),
  Event(DateTime(2021, 1, 1), [
    "Go to gym",
    "Duis congue enim ut justo interdum, id porta turpis varius"
  ]),
  Event(DateTime(2021, 1, 2), [
    "Running",
    "Fusce in varius lorem. Praesent accumsan metus at sem faucibus"
  ]),
];

//Function
mydates() {
  var eventDayMap = <DateTime, List<Event>>{};

  for (var event in eventList) {
    print(event.date); // Prints each element in the List<Event>
    print(event.title);
    //print(event.description);

    // Adding them to the eventDayMap
    // Creates a new list
    // Adds only the date and title
    (eventDayMap[event.date] ??= []).add(event);
  }
  print(eventDayMap);
  //print(eventDayMap.runtimeType);
  return eventDayMap;
}
```

Now it returns

```
2021-01-01 00:00:00.000
[Buy milk, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sem]
2021-01-01 00:00:00.000
[Go to gym, Duis congue enim ut justo interdum, id porta turpis varius]
2021-01-02 00:00:00.000
[Running, Fusce in varius lorem. Praesent accumsan metus at sem faucibus]
```

Not exactly what I was looking for but it might be a better solution.